# How can I improve my prototype of my Processing rhythm game?

Tags: java, javascript, processing

I am trying to create a rhythm game in Processing similar to Osu. The game is supposed to create a block based on the music that is being played. At the stage I'm at, the game hangs whenever the music plays. The music gets distorted as well. Please help!

```
int start;
float xpos;
float ypos;

int counter = 0;

Boolean menu = true;
Boolean game = false;

import ddf.minim.*;

click Clicker;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;

void setup() {
  size (800,800);
  Clicker = new click();
  start = millis();

}

void draw() {
  if (menu) {
    text("Welcome to My Game!", 300, 350);
    text("Get ready to play", 400, 375);
    text("Click on the screen to start", 275, 400);
    textSize(35);


  }

  if(game) {
    Clicker.display();
    Clicker.click();
    Clicker.gui();

    int timer = millis()/1000;
    text("Time: "+ timer, 10, 760);

    minim = new Minim(this);
    song = minim.loadFile("Bohemian Rhapsody.mp3");
    song.play();

  }
}

class click {
  float xpos;
  float ypos = 50;
  float wide;
  float high;
  float colour;

  click() {
    wide = 30;
    high = 30;
   colour = 45;
  }

  void display() {
    background (255);
    fill(colour);
    rect(xpos, ypos, wide, high);
  }

  void click() {
    if (mousePressed) {
      if (mouseX >= xpos && mouseX <= xpos + 30) {
        if (mouseY >= ypos && mouseY <= ypos + 30) {
          counter = counter + 1;
          xpos = random(0, 750);
          ypos = random(50, 650);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void gui() {
    text("Score: " + counter, 10, 790);
    textSize(35);
    line(0, 700, 800, 700);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (menu) {
    menu = false;
    game = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There a few things to fix and improve:

1. Syntax / flow
2. Game design
3. Rhythm games

**1. Syntax / flow**

The reason why probably music gets distorted is because you're initializing the minim library multi times in the draw() function. Similarly, you should call play() once for your song. Here's a version of your code with a few lines moved:

```
import ddf.minim.*;

float xpos;
float ypos;

int counter = 0;

Boolean menu = true;
Boolean game = false;

click Clicker;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer song;

void setup() {
  size (800,800);
  Clicker = new click();
  //initialize the library once, when you setup
  minim = new Minim(this);
  song = minim.loadFile("Bohemian Rhapsody.mp3");
}

void draw() {
  if (menu) {
    text("Welcome to My Game!", 300, 350);
    text("Get ready to play", 400, 375);
    text("Click on the screen to start", 275, 400);
    textSize(35);


  }

  if(game) {
    Clicker.display();
    Clicker.click();
    Clicker.gui();

    int timer = millis()/1000;
    text("Time: "+ timer, 10, 760);

  }
}

class click {
  float xpos;
  float ypos = 50;
  float wide;
  float high;
  float colour;

  click() {
    wide = 30;
    high = 30;
   colour = 45;
  }

  void display() {
    background (255);
    fill(colour);
    rect(xpos, ypos, wide, high);
  }

  void click() {
    if (mousePressed) {
      if (mouseX >= xpos && mouseX <= xpos + 30) {
        if (mouseY >= ypos && mouseY <= ypos + 30) {
          counter = counter + 1;
          xpos = random(0, 750);
          ypos = random(50, 650);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void gui() {
    text("Score: " + counter, 10, 790);
    textSize(35);
    line(0, 700, 800, 700);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (menu) {
    menu = false;
    game = true;
    song.play();//play the song once, when entering game mode
  }
}
```

**2. Game design**

There are plenty of resources online on the topic and simply playing games should help pin point a couple of basic questions to ask:

- What is the goal/reward of the game (does a plumber save a princes, is a puzzle solved) ?
- How does the game work (what are the rules/mechanics/when does a level start/end/ do you win/lose/ how ?)

Your current version presents a never ending level where time increases and as well as score as long as the player chooses to click a box. Try placing a time limit per level. You can always introduce complexity to level up (introduce two boxes at the same time with a preferred click sequence, etc.). You've mentioned the Osu rhythm game, but you should really play it and try to break down it's rules/algorithms into steps.

**3. Rhythm games**

The fun part about rhythm is the tight connection between what you see, what you hear (which is a pretty goal to get right on it's own) but also how/when you interact.

Currently if you comment you the music, this makes no difference to the game at all. There is no relationship to the music at all. You should try adding user interaction based on key moments in the music. 
Minim already provides some [onset and beat detection](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/beatdetect_class_beatdetect.html). You should have a play with that. (Alternatively, you can try software or services like [Echonest](http://developer.echonest.com/) to do the music analysis and extract the key moments, or simply add markers yourself manually in a software and export a csv file if that allows it)

Have fun!